# How can I create an autocomplete with MongoDB full text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I want to create an autocomplete input box that shows word suggestions as users type.

Basically, my problem is that when I use the $text operator for searching strings in a document, the queries will only match on complete stemmed words. This is for the same reason that if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match the document. However, a search on either blueberry or blueberries would match.

```
find = {$text: { $search:  'blue' } };
```

^ (doesn't match blueberry or bluebird on a document.)

I want to be able to do this. I want to match 'blueberry' or 'bluebird' with 'blue', and initially I thought this was possible by using a 'starts with' (^) regular expression, but it seems like $text and $search only accepts a string; not a regexp.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this that is not excessively complex to implement/maintain. So far, I've only seen people trying to accomplish this by creating a new collection with the results of running a map/reduce across the collection with the text index.

I do not want to use ElasticSearch or Solr because I think it is overkill for what I am trying to do, and although I sometimes think that eventually I will have no other choice, I still cannot believe that there is not a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement auto-complete feature using MongoDB search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892947/implement-auto-complete-feature-using-mongodb-search)

Comment: You might want to see my answer there.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB full text search matches whole words only, so it is inherently not suitable for auto complete.

> The $text operator can search for words and phrases. The query matches on the complete stemmed words. For example, if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match the document. However, a search on either blueberry or blueberries will match.

(Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Atlas Search natively in MongoDB Atlas to achieve this. You will have to first add the [autocomplete field mapping](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/define-field-mappings/#autocomplete) in your index definition before you can use the [autocomplete operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/autocomplete/) to your query. This can be accomplished through the Visual Editor or the JSON editor - there's a [tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/autocomplete-tutorial/) which walks you through how to implement it.

Here's the index definition template from the docs:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true|false,
    "fields": {
      "<field-name>": [
        {
          "type": "autocomplete",
          "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
          "tokenization": "edgeGram|rightEdgeGram|nGram",
          "minGrams": <2>,
          "maxGrams": <15>,
          "foldDiacritics": true|false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the query, where you can also specify support for typo-tolerance via the `fuzzy` parameter:

```
{
  $search: {
    "index": "<index name>", // optional, defaults to "default"
    "autocomplete": {
      "query": "<search-string>",
      "path": "<field-to-search>",
      "tokenOrder": "any|sequential",
      "fuzzy": <options>,
      "score": <options>
    }
  }
}
```