# MongoDB Full Text Search in an Array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I have a Schema like this:

```
const AyoSchema = new Schema({
images: Array,
```

Images is an array in which objects are stored in such format:

```
{
id: a uuid here, 
name: a string here,
url: a url here, 
topic: a string here 
}
```

What i want to do is,
I want to search the name property of all objects in images array without invloving much work of indexes,

How shall i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could handle it. If you want to return only the matching documents, it's a little more complicated.

I assume you want to return only the matched items. In order to do so you will need to use the aggregation pipeline, specifically the $unwind and $match operators.

[Check out a live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/badeUySip2y)

Consider the following:

#### Database

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
    images: [
      {
        id: ObjectId("123123224454323123121314"),
        name: "foo",
        url: "cdn.domain.com/images/foo",
        topic: "lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("222123224454323123121314"),
        name: "bar",
        url: "cdn.domain.com/images/bar",
        topic: "lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("333323224454323123121314"),
        name: "baz",
        url: "cdn.domain.com/images/baz",
        topic: "lorem ipsum"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
    images: [
      {
        id: ObjectId("888823224454323123121314"),
        name: "text",
        url: "cdn.domain.com/images/text",
        topic: "lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("999993224454323123121314"),
        name: "foo",
        url: "cdn.domain.com/images/pic",
        topic: "lorem ipsum"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$images"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "images.name": "foo" // <-- replace "foo" with your query
    }
  }
])
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
    "images": {
      "id": ObjectId("123123224454323123121314"),
      "name": "foo",
      "topic": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "cdn.domain.com/images/foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
    "images": {
      "id": ObjectId("999993224454323123121314"),
      "name": "foo",
      "topic": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "cdn.domain.com/images/pic"
    }
  }
]
```

## Update

To include regex.

[Live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4qiWVhttDhM)

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$images"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "images.name": {
        "$regex": "fo*"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: And, How would i do the same with regexes?

Comment: Why would you need to use regex? This query is based upon matching full text.

Comment: I need regex, Because MongoDB Full Text Search Doesnt Support Auto-Complete.
Read the 2nd step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892947/implement-auto-complete-feature-using-mongodb-search

Comment: Please see the update to my answer.