# Most efficient way to implement autocomplete with Mongodb .net core

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to implement autocomplete on a stand-alone instance of MongoDB using C#.
I saw MongoDB has `Autocomplete` search on **MongoDB Atlas** but I want to have it on **our stand-alone instance**.
I also know that we can implement it using `Regex` like below.

```
var filter = builder.Regex(x => x.Name, new BsonRegularExpression(new Regex($"^{request.Term}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

Is there any more efficient way to implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement auto-complete feature using MongoDB search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892947/implement-auto-complete-feature-using-mongodb-search)

Comment: @Fcmam5 No. I saw that answer. Looking for a better way.